# PostgreSQL WHERE IN LIKE query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I was wondering if it's possible to do a query using the IN clause where the options inside it are LIKE clauses, for example I have my existing SQL which returns the same results as I intend it just seems like a round about way to do it.

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE application_name NOT LIKE '%psql%'
AND (current_timestamp - state_change) > INTERVAL '30 minutes'
AND state IN (
    SELECT state
    FROM pg_stat_activity
    WHERE state LIKE '%idle%'
    OR state LIKE '%disabled%'
)
```

Is there a way to replace with something along the lines of

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE application_name NOT LIKE '%psql%'
AND (current_timestamp - state_change) > INTERVAL '30 minutes'
AND state IN ('%idle%', '%disabled%')
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use **SIMILAR TO** instead of **LIKE**

`AND state SIMILAR TO '%(idle|disabled)%'`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: This answer solved my problem but if SIMILAR TO can do this with singular options and multiple options then why would someone ever use LIKE?

Comment: @Trent `SIMILAR TO` uses regex under the hood. So I expect It may work slower than `LIKE`. But I don't think it's your case

Comment: This is awesome!!!! I can't believe I didn't find this out, say, in 2016... i had to wait 7 frickin years to find this gem!!

Answer (score 17):

Actually using `something IN (<value list>)` is similar to `something = any(array[<value list>])` in the PostgreSQL:

```
postgres=# explain select 1 where 'a' in ('a','b','c');
                        QUERY PLAN                        
----------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
   One-Time Filter: ('a'::text = ANY ('{a,b,c}'::text[]))
(2 rows)
```

Fortunately we can use `like` or even `ilike` instead of `=`:

```
select 1 where 'aa' ilike any(array['%A%','%B%','%C%']);
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

So in your case it could be

```
... state LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%idle%', '%disabled%'])
```

And the additional advantage: it can be passed as a parameter from the client application.

Answer (score 6):

`x IN (a, b)` can be consisidered shorthand for `x = ANY (ARRAY[a,b])`. Similarly, `x IN (SELECT ...)` and `x = ANY (SELECT ...)`.

The `=` can actually be replaced by any binary operator. Thus, you can use:

```
SELECT ... WHERE x LIKE ANY (SELECT ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Users of MySQL or Oracle may find it a bit different, but in PostGreSQL, to filter data using LIKE clause, one should use something like -

```
select * from table-name where column-name::text like '%whatever-to-be-searched%'
```

Answer (score 0):

"where name like any (array['%ab%', '%gh%', %xy%']);"

this is much faster then "SIMILAR TO".